# import FacebookSDK in Xcode 6 - swift

Tags: facebook, swift, xcode6, facebook-sdk-4.0

I followed this tutorial [Xcode 6 Tutorial: iOS 8.0 Facebook Login in Swift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mR-VGbXCGag).

But inside my Bridge-Header.h Xcode gives me an error in the import line (`#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`): `'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found`

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when moving my project to another location. If you remove the FacebookSDK.framework from your project and add it again, the "file not found" error should disappear. Keep in mind that you must not check "Copy items ..." when adding the Facebook framework.

Comment: I actually fixed the problem, but I have no idea how O.o
Maybe it was an Xcode update, maybe it was any removing and re-adding that I did.